# Python 2.7- convert array of strings to csv

Tags: string, python-2.7, csv, numpy, set

I have set of strings, that I want to save as data frame (one column, each string to separated cell). Each string has the following structure:

```
u'word word word\n word word\nword word word word word word \nword word word word'
```

I tried to use 
`np.savetxt("dataframe.csv", strings, fmt='%s', delimiter='\t')`but due to newline `\n` character, each CSV cell contain one line instead of whole string. Any ideas how to solve it easily?

Comment: can you post a small sample data set and your desired data set / file?

Comment: Replace `\n` characters with space for each string and then pass that to `np.savetxt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas.DataFrame.to_csv(path_or_buf='', sep=','). after coverting to csv, then you can  write it in a file as .csv file